# How to specify neurons connection to the next layer in keras?

Tags: keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I am trying to build a neural network in Keras with pre-specified connections. For example:

[partially connected layers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5lnx.png)

For example if my input X has feature 'a' I would like to only train neuron 'b' in the next layer.

I am not sure how to specify connections between layers in keras.

Thanks!

Comment: You can specify the connections using the Input layer in the keras API. You can find additional details [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I looked at the link before, but the functional API examples given in the link is different from what I am interested in as far as I understand. I would like to train only certain neurons depending on the input features. for eexampleif my input has feature 'a' I would like to only train neuron 'A' in the next layer

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can use a combination of `Lambda` layers and `merge`.
So it can be done through something like :

```
input = Input((6,))
# Split input to 3 streams
a = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, [0,4]], output_shape=(2,))(input)
b = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 0:5], output_shape=(5,))(input)
c = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 5], output_shape=(1,))(input)

# Build the hidden layer
hidden = merge([a, c, b], mode='concat')

# Split the hidden output to 2 streams
aa = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 0:1], output_shape=(2,))(hidden)
d = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 2], output_shape=(1,))(hidden)

# Build the output layer
output = merge([aa, d], mode='concat')

model = Model(input, output)
```